# Android multicast working very unreliably

Tags: android, networking, android-6.0-marshmallow, multicast, android-permissions

I've got some networking code that has worked for a couple years in Android.  Now, with a device running Android 6.0, it is only partially working.  I've also gotten reports from users with issues likely caused by the same problem when running on Samsung Tab S2s, but I don't know what OS version they're running yet.  Basically, the devices seem to transmit just fine, but no data ever actually gets received by them.  Other devices on the same network can send and receive with no problems.  There are caveats (see below) where the setup works fine, though.

Best I can guess so far, is the multicast group isn't being correctly joined by my Android 6.0 device.  But that doesn't explain why one router seems to work fine.  Any ideas how to fix it so all valid multicast addresses are working correctly?  If there is no fix, how bad is it to use the reserved 224.0.0.251 address for non routing messages?

Devices:
A - Note 5 running Android 5.1.1
B - nVidia Shield Tablet running Android 6.0

Routers:
X - WIFI Linksys EA4500 router
Y - WIFI Windows 10 PC hosted network

Findings:
1 - UDP/TCP unicast seem to work fine on both devices and routers
2 - UDP multicast works with 224.0.0.251 on router X (didn't try router Y)
3 - UDP multicast works on router Y, with the address 239.2.3.1 
4 - UDP multicast with the address 239.2.3.1, or any other valid address I tried, partially works on router X.  Device A can tx/rx and device B can only tx.

My relevant manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
```

And here is the simplified code that has worked for every other device I've used:

```
try
{
    mRxSocket = new MulticastSocket( APort );

    mRxSocket.joinGroup( AMulticastAddress );

    mRxSocket.setSoTimeout( 0 );

    final WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)getSystemService( Context.WIFI_SERVICE );

    mMyMulticastLock = wm.createMulticastLock( "WAKELOCK_STRING" );
    mMyMulticastLock.acquire();

    int maxPacketSize = 1024*64;
    final byte packetBuffer[] = new byte[maxPacketSize];
    final DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( packetBuffer, maxPacketSize );

    mRxSocket.receive( packet );

    // it never gets past the receive call.  No data is ever received by this thread...
}
catch( final IOException e )
{
    mRxSocket = null;

    //connection failed

    //never gets here unless the network is disconnected
}
```

Comment: Have you updated your app to ask for permissions on runtime? http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score -1):

Multicasting is disabled in 5.0 and up by default... don't know why google would do such a thing. but the only solution i could find was flash a custom kernel with multicasting enabled

You could also try converting multicasting to unicasting

Comment: this needs citation